# How to use summation to get the value of a binary number?

Tags: functions

How to use summation to get the value of a binary number?

I want to do this:

$(x_{n}x_{n-1}...x_{0})=\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_{i}\cdot b^{i} $

But it seems that I can only do something like this:

$\sum_{i=1}^{10}i^{2}$

I imagine that there is some indexation function which will help to do so, I also know how to do in another way, but is it possible to do this using summation?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do... express a binary number in its decimal form? Your equations aren't... equations. The expression in parentheses looks more like a factorial than your summation.

Comment: Please give us some working resp. non-working *Mathematica* code showing what you want. *Especially* the form in which your input is given.

Comment: @CHM Yes. The equation is from [this](http://www.idc.ac.il/tecs/) book.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: @celtschk I want to decompose the binary number and get it on decimal form. Like this: $1001 \rightarrow1\cdot 2^{3}+0\cdot 2^{2}+0\cdot 2^{1}+1\cdot 2^{0}$

Comment: $1001$ is not Mathematica code (unless you take is as the Mathematica representation of the number one thousand and one, which you probably did not mean). So what does your *Mathematica* input look like? A string? A list of integers? Or what?

Comment: @celtschk A binary integer number?

Comment: You mean, `2^^1001`? But then, that's already the number 9, in that case it's not clear to me what you want.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I think you should check David answer. It seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
binDigits = {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

Alternative 1:

```
binDigits.Table[2^i, {i, Length[binDigits] - 1, 0, -1}]

(* ==> 190 *)
```

Alternative 2:

```
Sum[2^(Length[binDigits] - i) binDigits[[i]], {i, Length[binDigits]}]

(* ==> 190 *)
```

Alternative 3:

```
FromDigits[binDigits, 2]

(* ==> 190 *)
```

If your binary number is given as a string you could do the following first:

```
binDigits = ToExpression /@ Characters["10111110"]

(* ==> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

If your binary number is given as a decimal numbers with 1's and 0's only (actually a misrepresentation) you could try:

```
binDigits = ToExpression /@ Characters@ToString@10111110

(* ==> {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

Comment: But isn't it possible with summation?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I clearly see a summation in there. Try looking again (alternative 2).

Comment: "Alternative 1" could have been written more compactly as `binDigits .2^Range[Length[binDigits] - 1, 0, -1]`. Still, if a function like `FromDigits[]` did not exist in *Mathematica*, the two other alternatives do a bit too much arithmetic for the purpose; one would usually prefer Horner's method for this: `Fold[(2 #1 + #2) &, 0, binDigits]`.

Comment: I agree with J.M.  If `Sum` is mandatory, how about `i = 0; Sum[2^(i++) d, {d, Reverse@binDigits}]` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard With the question vague as it was, I din't want to spend too much time on this, or it might have been for naught.  Also, all the fancy stuff may be quicker to execute or shorter to write, but it is harder to grasp for beginners.

Comment: My comment was in no way meant to be a criticism.  I do think the `Fold` method is "best" but that's not what the OP asked for, and as for my `Sum` I've just got the bug to write terse code the last few days.  "Nothing to see here, move along..." :-)

Answer (score 4):

A solution using the product of the binary digits and the relevant power of the chosen base:

```
Clear[s];
Options[s] := {Base -> 2, Totalled -> True};
s[number_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{digitVals = 
    Reverse@Flatten@
       NestList[# OptionValue@Base &, {1}, Length@number - 1] number},
   If[OptionValue@Totalled, Total@digitVals, digitVals]]
```

Sample input and output using `IntegerDigits` to obtain a list representation of a decimal number as binary:

```
s[IntegerDigits[100, 2], Base -> 2, Totalled -> True]
s[IntegerDigits[100, 2], Base -> 2, Totalled -> False]

(*  

-> 100
-> {64, 32, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0}

*)
```

Answer (score 4):

I offer this paragon of elegance and readability:

```
binDigits = {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
Total@MapIndexed[#1*2^(Length@binDigits - First@#2) &, binDigits]
(*190*)
```

(or we could use [BaseForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseForm.html)).

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to use the somation notation?

```
 binDigits = ToExpression /@ Characters["111"]

\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(Length[
   binDigits]\)]\(binDigits[[i]]\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(Length[binDigits] - i\)]\)\)
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And calculates to the answer 7.

Comment: No, I want to decompose the binary number and get it on decimal form. Like this: $1001 \rightarrow1\cdot 2^{3}+0\cdot 2^{2}+0\cdot 2^{1}+1\cdot 2^{0}$

Comment: You probably want to use `IntegerDigits` instead of `Characters`.  That way you can compute with them as numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers so far assume that the input is a list of integers representing the digits. As the original question didn't specify the form of the input, here some alternatives.

**Taking a string as input**

Of course the simplest way to turn a string of binary digits into a number is

```
fromBinary[s_String] /; StringMatchQ[s,RegularExpression["[01]+"]] :=
  ToExpression["2^^" <> s]
```

(the complicated part here just checks that the string indeed contains a binary number).

However that would not involve an explicit summation (well, somewhere internally it probably does, but that's hidden), therefore I give another solution containing an explicit sum:

```
fromBinary[s_String] /; StringMatchQ[s,RegularExpression["[01]+"]] :=
  Total[2^(StringLength[s]-StringPosition[s,"1"][[All,1]])]
```

The explicit sum is in the call of `Total` which just adds up all elements in the list given to it.

**Taking an integer as input**

OK, now I'm assuming that the input is given as an integer whose decimal digits match the binary digits of the intended number (i.e. when given the number `1001` — that is, one thousand and one — it interprets it as the digit sequence `1`, `0`, `0`, `1`). Of course, given the function above, it's easy to do that (I omit the binary check here):

```
fromBinary[i_Integer] := fromBinary[IntegerString[i]]
```

Another alternative would be to use `IntegerDigits[i]` and feed the result into the code given in the previous answers.

Comment: "All the answers so far assume that the input is a list of integers representing the digits". Not true, I offered solutions for string, numeric and list inputs. Please look at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Ah, indeed, I didn't see that. However, given that my solutions (except for the last one which I only sketched) do not turn the input into a list, they still add something. I now changed the beginning of my post accordingly.