# "A number in base b" and pure functions: why doesn't b^^# & work?

Tags: evaluation, syntax, number-bases

Why do the following not work (in Mathematica 7)?

```
2^^ # & /@ {1000, 1101}
```

and

```
2^^ # & @ 1101
```

This does work:

```
2^^1101
```

giving, as expected:

```
(*13*)
```

(This also works:

```
BaseForm[#, 2] & /@ {13, 14}
```

)

See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DigitsInNumbers.html) for further information ("Digits in numbers")

Comment: Note that `2^^ 1101` doesn't work either, which already is a strong hint that one shouldn't expect `2^^ # &` to work.

Comment: I like how in MMA questions can appear to be censored curse words. What the F^^@@#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that the notation `base^^digits` is interpreted at *parsing time*, not evaluation time.  I explained the difference [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4672/12).

You can use `FromDigits` instead:

```
fromBaseTwo = FromDigits[#, 2]& 

fromBaseTwo["10011"]
```

Note that I used a string as input.  `FromDigits` works both with strings and lists of digits.

Comment: I feel that this previous question says it all. Vote to close this one?

Comment: @Sjoerd Personally I'm fine with closing.  Maybe the FromDigits part (how to actually construct that pure function) is a worthwhile addition here?

Comment: Didn't we cover that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5831/how-to-use-summation-to-get-the-value-of-a-binary-number)?

Comment: @Sjoerd I did consider voting to close briefly, before posting an answer, but for some reason I didn't.  Just do what you feel is correct :-)

Comment: I wish I could just vote to close without casting a super close vote. I'm hesitating because of this pure function part in the question, but actually it doesn't make  much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat messed-up way to do something like what you wanted to do:

```
ToExpression["2^^" <> ToString[#]] & /@ {1000, 1101}
{8, 13}
```